Flux.1 Schnell image generator issue, GPU resources getting exhausted after 1 prompt
So, I tried to train a prompt based image generation model using FLUX.1-schnell. I used Lightning AI Studio (an alternate to Google Colab), that helped me to access to L40 GPU, that came with 48gb VRAM (since the minimum requirement is 24 GB.
I trained it with a LoRA, which was setup with the help of "ai-toolkit" cloned from a GitHub repo "click here", at 1200 steps with 35 images as training dataset. reference link
The first prompt worked pretty fine and generated a desired result, but when I went to generate a second image it said:

CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 74.00 MiB. GPU 0 has a total capacity of 44.53 GiB of which 71.25 MiB is free. Process 26865 has 44.45 GiB memory in use. Of the allocated memory 43.89 GiB is allocated by PyTorch, and 56.25 MiB is reserved by PyTorch but unallocated.

I tried to run the code on the Jupyter Notebook, which was successful and was able to create safetensors after training the model.
Now, for the first prompt, I ran the cell with the following code:
import torch
from diffusers import FluxPipeline
# Load Flux
pipe = FluxPipeline.from_pretrained("black-forest-labs/FLUX.1-schnell", torch_dtype=torch.float16).to("cuda")

# Load your fine-tuned model
pipe.load_lora_weights("/teamspace/studios/this_studio/ai-toolkit/output/fluxGirl/fluxGirl.safetensors", adapter_name="default")
# Generate an image
prompt = "anime girl with red hair drinking coffee"

image = pipe(prompt, height=512, width=512).images[0]
# Save the image
image.save("test1.png")

It gave me a good result, but for the second image, I kept everything the same and changed the prompt and then ran the cell, but got the above error.
How to fix this, so that I can atleast generate three images at a time.
Another thing, since I have already save the output files such as:
model.safetensor and optimizers.pt image,
Where should I make changes to not entirely download the model when once the GPU and codes are initiated.

If you load everything from scratch and run the second prompt, does it work? If the second prompt is longer, it may simply require more GPU memory than you have

tl;dr remove the following lines because they break PIL image conversion:
train_dataset.data = train_dataset.data / 255

val_dataset.data = val_dataset.data / 255

In detail:
This is the __getitem__ method of the MNIST dataset:
def __getitem__(self, index: int) -> Tuple[Any, Any]:
    img, target = self.data[index], int(self.targets[index])

    # doing this so that it is consistent with all other datasets
    # to return a PIL Image
    img = Image.fromarray(img.numpy(), mode="L")

    if self.transform is not None:
        img = self.transform(img)

    if self.target_transform is not None:
        target = self.target_transform(target)

    return img, target

The data item is first transformed into a PIL image, then sent through the transforms that convert it to a tensor.
PIL expects the input to be of dtype uint8. By default, the data attribute tensor in the dataset is dtype uint8.
When you divide by 255, you convert the tensor from uint8 to float32.
This causes PIL to produce weird results. For example:
# take a chunk of an image as an example
original_array = dataset1.data[0][8:12, 8:12].numpy()
print(original_array)
> [[219 253 253 253]
 [ 80 156 107 253]
 [  0  14   1 154]
 [  0   0   0 139]]

# scale by dividing by 255
scaled_array = original_array/255
print(scaled_array)
> [[0.85882353 0.99215686 0.99215686 0.99215686]
 [0.31372549 0.61176471 0.41960784 0.99215686]
 [0.         0.05490196 0.00392157 0.60392157]
 [0.         0.         0.         0.54509804]]

# applying PIL transform to original array results in the same output
pil_original = np.array(Image.fromarray(original_array, mode='L'))
print(pil_original)
> [[219 253 253 253]
 [ 80 156 107 253]
 [  0  14   1 154]
 [  0   0   0 139]]

# applying PIL transform to scale array results in messed up values
pil_scaled = np.array(Image.fromarray(scaled_array, mode='L'))
print(pil_scaled)
> [[123 123 123 123]
 [123 123 235  63]
 [192 191 191 191]
 [191 191 239  63]]

